# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-select' with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

module import is not working for me. I'm tried different solutions provided from stack overflow and other.
These are steps I'm follow the react-select

```
npm install --save @types/react-select
```

import the module like this

```
import Select from "react-select"
```

but I got the error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-select'

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactSelect from 'react-select'
export class Select extends extends React.Component<someProps>{

render(){
   return(
  <Select id="color" options={options} />
);
}
}
```

But I can't find the way to fixed this.

Comment: Where does this error occur: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-select'`? Is it shown by TS in editor or by JS in runtime?

Comment: it's came at the run the project. js run time

Comment: Did you run the bundling process after installing the package? Does `npm list --depth=0` shows `react-select`?

Comment: I tried it now. It's there in the list

Comment: You didn't answer about bundling though

Comment: I did't get that. You need to webpack configurations also?

Comment: Every time you make some edits to your code, as well as when installing a package, you have to rebuild (re-bundle) your project. So if you use Webpack (`npm run build`), you should run it. If you use create-react-app, you should run `npm start`

Comment: Yes. I did it too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183556/discussion-between-namindu-sanchila-and-nurbol-alpysbayev).

Comment: Sorry I ran out of ideas. My guesses is something is wrong with your build process, or maybe... there's a hidden character in the module name (I would retype it by hand) :D

Comment: ohh!! thanks you for helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue having here. Issue is both `@types/react-select` and `react-select` added to the `package.json`

Comment: This was the solution that I got.

Answer (score 9):

I got solution by `npm i react-select`.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Actually I don`t know more then that on this topic but I got the solution with this. So for other case should I provide solutions even I don`t know explanation ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to provide answers if you don't know if, or how, they work.

Comment: Might be not a good idea but some one gets the solution which is more important I think ?

Comment: Thanks @AshwaniPanwar. Worked for me. Seems like react needs bare installation - npm i/install react-select as opposed to - npm install @types/react-select!

Answer (score 4):

You have an error:

```
npm install --save @type/react-select
```

instead of

```
npm install --save @types/react-select
```

Also I would recommend to use `--save-dev` instead of `--save` because you don't need typings in production.

Comment: yar sorry for that I'm used the npm install --save @types/react-select it's same as you provided. In the questions it should be edited.

Comment: yar I had use environment too. but this snippets for the example how im used it

Comment: It's also correct in the code. only error I got is Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-select'

Answer (score 0):

My error was a bit different since it involves react-select-async-paginate.

So in my case, I had to use,

```
npm install react-select react-select-async-paginate
```

or

```
yarn add react-select react-select-async-paginate
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that the project I am working on uses an old version of `react-select`. In version 5, `react-select` was rewritten in typescript, and the types package (`@types/react-select`) became a stub package, with no actual type definitions in it.

So if you are using `react-select` in version <5, you have to specify the version of the types definitions package, that matches (or is close to) the version you are using. For example, if your `react-select` is in version 3.2.0, the definition in `package.json` would be:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-select": "^3.1.2"
  }
```

For available versions of the package, visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-select?activeTab=versions